# How to add a second stylesheet to the editor

Tags: theme-development, customization, themes, visual-editor

Is it possible to add another stylesheet from my theme directory, to the `Appearance > Editor` screen?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! Any `.css` file in the top-level of your theme will show up there.

e.g.:

```
/wp-content/themes/<your-theme>/custom-style.css
```

will show up in that list as "custom-style.css", linked and editable.

Answer (score 1):

This only works if you have FTP-access

Create a {name}.css file.
Upload this file to your theme folder

```
wp-content/themes/{theme_name}/{name}.css
```

After this refresh the page and you should see the file there.

You probably want to add a second line of code to your header.php file to make sure the css file is used.

Something like:

```
<link href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory')?>/{name}.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
```

This goes between your `<head>`-tags